# Flask Curl POST - 500 Internal Secer Error - Pyrest API

Tags: python, rest, ubuntu, curl, server

500 Internal Server Error when trying to set up a pyrest.

I am using a guide from https://linuxhint.com/rest_api_python/ to try and set up a rest API within my python 3 server, i am using the code below in api.py and using terminal, both the first GET requests i have put in work and display the data fine, when it comes to the POST request which is what i am trying to get working on the Virtual Machine with Ubuntu on i get a 500 internal error...

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

accounts = [
    {'name': "Billy", 'balance': 450.0},
    {'name': "Kelly", 'balance': 250.0}
     ]


@app.route("/accounts", methods=["GET"])
def getAccounts():
    return jsonify(accounts)
    
    
@app.route("/account/<id>", methods=["GET"])
def getAccount(id):
    id = int(id) - 1
    return jsonify(accounts[id])
    
@app.route("/account", methods=["POST"])
def addAccount():
    name = request.json['name']
    balance = request.json['balance']
    data = {'name': name, 'balance': balance}
    accounts.append(data)
    
    return jsonify(data)    
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8080)
```

I am guessing the code is correct and it is more of a server issue, problem is i am trying to install this service onto my server to get the POST method to work, not sure if i am missing any steps.

I am using

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name": "Shovon", "balance": 100}' http://127.0.0.1:8080/account
```

To "Add" the data to the list of accounts which are within the api.py file.

Any help is appreciated, this is the first time i have used FLASK & APP.Route so please forgive me if its a newbie mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to import `request` from `Flask`, so the first two lines within your `addAccount()` function throw the 500 error. To fix the problem all you have to do is change the import line at the top to:

`from flask import Flask, jsonify, request`

Additionally one other thing to note is that it's encouraged to write function names following the PEP8 standard with an underscore between words and not camel case. Here's a fixed version of your file:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)

accounts = [
    {'name': "Billy", 'balance': 450.0},
    {'name': "Kelly", 'balance': 250.0}
     ]


@app.route("/accounts", methods=["GET"])
def get_accounts():
    return jsonify(accounts)
    
    
@app.route("/account/<id>", methods=["GET"])
def get_account(id):
    id = int(id) - 1
    return jsonify(accounts[id])
    
@app.route("/account", methods=["POST"])
def add_account():
    name = request.json['name']
    balance = request.json['balance']
    data = {'name': name, 'balance': balance}
    accounts.append(data)
    
    return jsonify(data)    
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8080)
```

Comment: Thank you! My next task is to implement this into my php site which which i have created, I am guessing this will require a new question, 

I have a form which pushes Name, Email, Product & Price through a html form with POST. I am guessing this code will not work and i will need to implement my own variables into the code i have above.